# Is interval arithmetic an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) an integral domain, considering we cannot divide by intervals containing zero?

- Addition: $$[x_1, x_2] + [y_1, y_2] = [x_1+y_1, x_2+y_2]$$
- Subtraction: $$[x_1, x_2] - [y_1, y_2] = [x_1-y_2, x_2-y_1]$$
- Multiplication: $$[x_1, x_2] \cdot [y_1, y_2] = [\min \{x_1 y_1,x_1 y_2,x_2 y_1,x_2 y_2\}, \max\{x_1 y_1,x_1 y_2,x_2 y_1,x_2 y_2\}]$$
- Division:
  $$\frac{[x_1, x_2]}{[y_1, y_2]} = [x_1, x_2] \cdot \frac{1}{[y_1, y_2]},$$

where
$$
\frac{1}{[y_1, y_2]} = \left [\tfrac{1}{y_2}, \tfrac{1}{y_1} \right ], \mathrm{if}\;0 \notin [y_1, y_2] $$
$$\frac{1}{[y_1, 0]}   = \left [-\infty, \tfrac{1}{y_1} \right ] $$
$$\frac{1}{[0, y_2]}   = \left [\tfrac{1}{y_2}, \infty \right ] $$

Comment: It might be helpful to specify which operations you're considering this as a ring under.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the set of real intervals with interval arithmetic is not even a ring because:

- there are no additive inverses in interval arithmetic, except for the interval $[0,0]$.
- interval arithmetic is not distributive. It is *subdistributive*: $(I+J)K \subseteq IK+JK$, but equality does not hold in general.

Comment: See also [A distributive interval arithmetic](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/ms/distr.pdf) by Neumaier.

Comment: I did not get the "no additive inverses" part.

Comment: @Anixx, there is no interval $I$ such that $[0,1]+I=[0,0]$